# Ruby how to print part of the file name

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have two questions regarding Ruby.

For the below code#1, I am trying to print all the file names inside a folder, but "puts text" will gave me  "/folder1/folder2/filename1.txt" for example. How can I just print just "filename1" without the directory and the .txt

number1:

```
 Dir.glob('/folder1/folder2/*.txt').each do |text|
 puts text
```

number2:   i am trying to combine two array

```
 a = [16,5,6,8,7]
 b = [people,men,guys,boys,you]
```

the output will look like:

```
people:16, men:5, guys:6, boys:8, you:7
```

i converted a to string  by using .to_s but i still can't combine them.

Comment: Please post two separate questions if you have two separate questions.  Also, tell us what you're trying to accomplish.  The answers may vary depending on your end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `File.basename`:

```
Dir.glob('/folder1/folder2/*.txt').each do |path|
 puts File.basename(path, '.txt')
end
```

Comment: `File.basename` includes the file extension, which OP doesn't want. Perhaps you meant `File.basename(path, '.txt')`?